# OpenCV with VsCode : opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory. BUT can run the CMakeLists.txt

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I followed **this tutorial**( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-opencv-in-c-on-linux/) to install OpenCV(version = 4.x) in **wsl-1.** As I tried to test whether I have installed OpenCV correctly, it raised this **error: "opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory"**, when I click the button "run" in VsCode.

This is my .cpp file:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace cv; 
int main() 
{ 
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Then I tried another method ( [How to fix "fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory" for opencv4 installed in manjaro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58478074/how-to-fix-fatal-error-opencv2-core-hpp-no-such-file-or-directory-for-opencv)) to compile the .cpp file:

`g++ DisplayImage.cpp -o DisplayImage -I/usr/local/include/opencv4`

It gave me no results and no error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UnHo.png)

However:

1. I configured the includepath in "c_cpp_properties.json"

   ```
   {
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Linux",
               "includePath": [
                   "${workspaceFolder}",
                   "/usr/local/include/opencv4"
               ],
               "defines": [],
               "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
               "cStandard": "c17",
               "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
               "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
           }
       ],
       "version": 4
   }
   ```

   What's more, I can open this head files by clicking "go to Definition" . So, I am sure the head file "opencv2/opencv.hpp" exists and the include path is correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOQMj.png)

2 I could run CMake on this .cpp file without any error by following the tutorial. And I can realise the function of the .cpp file.
This is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
message(STATUS "OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS = ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message(STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNn2v.png)

Does anyone know the reason? And How to fix this? It seems, I can not "run" this .cpp file but can do CMake on it.

Thank you for your help.